# Why does the go Ethereum code reject odd number of digit hex numbers?

Tags: go-ethereum

This is a question specific to the go-ethereum implementation. It may be present in other implementations, but I haven't looked yet.

In [go-ethereum/common/bytes.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/common/bytes.go#L64), the function isHex returns false if an input has an odd number of digits, and I was wondering why:

```
func isHex(str string) bool {
    if len(str)%2 != 0 {
        return false
    }
    for _, c := range []byte(str) {
        if !isHexCharacter(c) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the context of Ethereum, hex is a set of *bytes* encoded in base 16. Since a byte is actually 256 values, it takes 2 hex characters to make up a byte. So if there are only 3 hex characters, you wouldn't know which pairs of characters made up the individual bytes.